# Removing trees from classified LiDAR based on polygon layer

Tags: qgis, lidar, las, pdal

I need to adjust the areas in a .las file where the trees and shrubs were cut last year.
There are basically 5 classes, with one class ("20") for taller vegetation.

Is there a simple workflow in QGIS or PDAL (command line) to filter out all points of this class within a polygon layer of the clearing area?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the [clipping exercise](https://pdal.io/en/latest/workshop/manipulation/clipping/clipping.html) in the PDAL workshop to achieve this. Instead of filtering out the points, use [`filters.overlay`](https://pdal.io/en/latest/stages/filters.overlay.html#) to assign alternative `Classification` values for the points that are both inside the polygon and meet the `where` expression (as assigned to `filters.overlay`) of `Classification == 20 || Classification ==5 || ...`.